# Categorize named entities extracted from text based on attributes like skills and location in python

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on a project that requires me to use NLTK. I am completely new to python and NLTK. I have text files in the form of CVs (resumes). I have recognized the unique named entities in them that look something like this:

```
set([u'JIRA', u'Scalatest', u'Java', u'Scala', u'Selenium',
u'TestNG',u'San Francisco', u'San Carlos', u'Scientific', u'Software QA
Engineer Teachscape', u'WORK', u'Green Card', u'Strong', 
u'Swivl Satarii Inc', u'DNA', u'CA', u'iOS', u'TestRails', u'HPQC',
u'Jira', u'India', u'US', u'Software QA', u'Selenium TestNG', u'SQL', 
u'South San Francisco', u'QA Engineer Software'])
```

I have 100s of such output. How do I go about categorizing the above output into skills, locations and Organization names and storing them in a JSON? I searched a lot but couldn't find many answers related to this. If there is no possible way to do this, I was thinking of taking the long way out by creating lists with all possible words for each of these categories and then looping through the above output to check which category has the particular word in its list.

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/alvations/a4a6e0cc24d2fd9aff86 (shameless plug), topic models and clustering (shameless plug for a friend: https://github.com/jonsafari/clustercat)

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at: github.com/jonsafari/clustercat. However,  got an error while executing this command 'make -j 4 CC=clang-omp'. The error is 'make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found'. I looked it up and tried executing ./configure, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: what commands did you run before `make` ?

Comment: As mentioned in the install instructions, i ran this command : brew update  &&  brew install clang-omp

Comment: It's going to sound silly but did you do `cd clustercat`? The makefile is surely there as shown on the github page: https://github.com/jonsafari/clustercat

Comment: Did you do `git clone https://github.com/jonsafari/clustercat.git && cd clustercat && make -j 4 CC=clang-omp` ?